# Cursor jumps to the first column after saving file when on a blank line

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode when the cursor is on a blank line and I save the document the cursor jumps to the first column of the line. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the line really isn't blank if the cursor isn't already in the first column.  The whitespace you have on that line is being removed when you do a save.  To prevent all the whitespace on a line from being removed, disable this setting:

`Files : Trim Trailing Whitespace`